# Swift 4 - Side Menu and Google Maps

Tags: swift, google-maps

How do I set the map (google map) on the background? I have a side menu set up on my app. But it is being blocked by the map. instead of the map being on the front, it is at the back of the map.

Comment: add screen shot of your storyboard

Comment: Don't add your SlideMenu inside of mapView go to storyboard and check the view controller scene and check your slide is inside of mapView if it is drag it out